# Implementing system-like buttons in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, button

Is there any way to implement a button exactly the same as play/pause button in iOS music player? I mean with same image, style, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a button with type `UIButtonTypeSystem` to get a similar behavior to the system buttons (fade when tapping, etc.). Images are only available to the application (the play/pause buttons are images in the music app's bundle). You need to either look for free images online, buy premium ones or consult with a graphic designer.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIButton` has a property `backgroundImageForState:`. Just set the images with this methods.

Comment: I know that. I mean is system button images available to set via this methods? How can I make a duplicate of system buttons? Is any way exists?